# Laravel keep printing 4 white spaces before the response

Tags: php, laravel, response

when I call to a controller the output that is going out is:

> ```
>     {success:true}
> ```

instead of:

> ```
> {success:true}
> ```

I have tried to grep and find something like: `"   <?php"` i got nothing.
I went on each and every class that I added and make sure they are not printing that, and they are not.
Its now 3 hours since I have discover that. I have no hints in the source control/
How can this be debugged?
if not, can I hook laravel till I find the problem and make it disapear via some sort of interception?

**UPDATE**
I went to the file: public/index.php and put this:

```
ob_start();
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$output = ob_get_clean();//$output will have the 4 spaces
```

So now the problem is hidden, but still needs to fix it since $output  has the 4 hidden spaces.

**Update 2**

the entire file

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

ob_start();
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$output = ob_get_clean();//$output will have the 4 spaces

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Thanks

Comment: It does of course not have to be 4 consecutive spaces with a `<?php` behind it. It could be `?>` followed by four spaces. Or it could be several PHP blocks with less than four spaces before/after them each …

Comment: @CBroe, this I know, but i dont know how to catch it

Comment: Well if you are using output buffering, you could simply trim the buffer contents before outputting it to the client … but if you want to really fix it, then you need to find out where those spaces are coming from. (And since no one here has access to your full code, only you can do that.)

Comment: Laravel and most libraries don't use closing PHP tag `?>` You can look for those and remove them or spaces after them.

Comment: It could be that your output file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM. t can cause problems like this. Save it (and every other file) as UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: @exabyssus how would i know which file is saved like that?. thanks

Comment: It depend on IDE or editor you use (Sublime, Notepad++...). What are you using? On Notepad++ for example there is a dedicated tab (Encoding)

Comment: @exabyssus im using phpstorm, I also have bash if it helps.

Comment: Give the whole code.

Comment: @exabyssus the hole code? if you mean public/index.php so i just put it

Comment: You don't need to post any code here. In PHPStorm is super ease, right click on main folder, synchronize, than right click again and choose Remove BOM. No file in your project should have BOM.

Answer (score 4):

Please check your **config/filesystems.php** file, I think there is a tab (or 4 white spaces) before **php opening** tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a full search using Phpstorm for example, search for

```
\r<?php \n<?php [space]<?php \t<?php
```

in my case I had a \n in my routes.php